# Cornerstone BigCommerce Checkbox Un Checked

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, helper

The code below is in the Cornerstone BigCom template. By default it display the checkbox as checked. Near the "My Billing address is the same as my Shipping address" section.

I'm trying to figure out how to display the checkbox as unchecked.
Been playing around with the syntax, but not working.
Help!

{{#if checkboxes}}

```
   {{#each checkboxes}}
        <input type="checkbox"
         value="{{value}}"
         name="{{name}}"
         id="{{name}}" 
         data-label="{{label}}" 
         class="form-checkbox" {{#if checked}}checked{{/if}} 
         {{#if private_id}}data-field-type="{{private_id}}"{
         {/if}}>
        
   <label class="form-label {{class}}" for="{{name}}">{{label}}</label>
     {{/each}}
      {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The checkout is rendered with react, you would need to trigger a state change to fully uncheck this option. You could add a script to your checkout page similar to this:

```
(function uncheckCheckbox(){
var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName('optimizedCheckout-form-checkbox');
checkBox[0].checked = false; 
}())
```

Note this will grab all the checkboxes on the checkout, but the [0] will select the first checkbox, being the one you're referencing. This may not be a 1:1 solution, but I hope it helps get you started! Thanks :)